# Windows 10 bluescreen after tunnel

Tags: windows, windows-10, tunnel

I have a very weird bluescreen behavior.

I am using a port tunnel to a remote server using e.g., the new bash, or something like putty (problem persists).

I then try to access the tunnel, e.g., via localhost:8888. But as soon as I do that, I receive a bluescreen with ATTEMPTED_EXECUTE_OF_NOEXECUTE_MEMORY.

I can reproduce this error every single time, and as said, regardless of how I open the tunnel or also how I access it, the bluescreen appears.

The same tunnel worked fine some weeks ago btw.